# Doctrine: Related entities are not updated after changing id in EventSubscriber (onFlush)

Tags: orm, doctrine, foreign-keys, auto-increment, composite-primary-key

I use composite primary keys for all Doctrine entities (multi-tenancy).

Example (yaml file):

```
id:
  website:
    associationKey: true
  id:
    type: integer
```

So I have to auto increment the id manually. All entities have id 1 as default.

Example (EventSubscriber):

```
class MultitenantEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'onFlush'
        ];
    }

    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $event)
    {
        $em = $event->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
            if ($entity instanceof AutoIncrementInterface) {
                $maxId = $em
                    ->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->select('MAX(e.id)')
                    ->from(get_class($entity), 'e')
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getSingleScalarResult();

                if ($maxId > 1) {
                    $entity->setId($maxId + 1);
                    $md = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
                    $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($md, $entity);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Everything is working so far.

**Problem:**

Foreign key in related entities is not updated when I recompute the change set. Entity A with for example auto incremented id 23 is created correctly, but Entity B with reference to A still returns reference id 1 instead of id 23.

```
$entityA = new A();
$entityA->setValue('foo');
$entityB = new B();
$entityB->setValue('bar');
$entityB->setA($entityA);
$em->persist($entityA);
$em->persist($entityB);
$em->flush();

echo $entityA->getId(); // Returns 23
echo $entityB->getA()->getId() // Returns 1 instead of 23
```

Of course I could update the entityB in the EventSubscriber, but I need a generic solution because there are a lot of entities with different relations.

Maybe someone has an idea how to "recompute"/"refresh" related entities?